# Liquibase - use sequence.nextval as inserted id

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I am trying to insert data into an Oracle database using Liquibase with .xml and .csv.
I'd like to use the primary key's sequence as inserted id. What is the proper syntax for this?

I tried in the .xml:

```
<changeSet>
   <loadData file="foo.csv" separator="," tableName="BAR" relativeToChangeLogFile="true">
      <column name="id" type="numeric" valueSequenceNext="BAR_SEQ.NEXTVAL"/>
      <column name="ukk" type="string"/>
      <column name="mukk" type="string"/>
      <column name="fukk" type="string"/>
   </loadData>
</changeSet>
```

in the .csv:

```
ukk,mukk,fukk
asd,fgh,jkl
lkj,hgf,dsa
```

But I am getting

```
Attribute 'valueSequenceNext' is not allowed to appear in element 'column'
```

What is the proper syntax for this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you take a look [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/nested-tags/column.html) there is no `valueSequenceNext` attribute for column. Try to use  `valueComputed` instead.